# WCF net.tcp communication error

Tags: wcf, exception, binding, net.tcp

I created a WCF Service with net.tcp binding and I was able to add a service reference to it in my console application without errors.

After doing this I am trying to self host this service in my console app. The service Host gets opened but when I call a method in the service with the service reference object I get this exception

'Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFServiceLibrary/Service2/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0800000. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:808.'

This is my cs file code

```
Main method()

 Service2Client sc2 = new Service2Client();
                Uri baseaddress = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFServiceLibrary/Service2/");

                ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service2Client), baseaddress);

                serviceHost.Open();

                Console.WriteLine(sc2.GetData(124)); --> exception comes at this point

                Console.ReadLine();
```

This is app.config in console app

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFServiceLibrary/Service2/"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService2"
        contract="ServiceReference2.IService2" name="NetTcpBinding_IService2">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService2" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!--<client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFServiceLibrary/Service2/"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="MyWCFServiceLibrary.IService2"
        name="endpointClient" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFServiceLibrary/Service2/"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService2"
        contract="ServiceReference2.IService2" name="NetTcpBinding_IService2">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>-->
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Environment: Vs2010

Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Your client config has the URL as net.tcp://localhost/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFServiceLibrary/Service2/ whereas your service is on net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFServiceLibrary/Service2/. The PORT Number is missing

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that:

1) the **firewall** is blocking the request. Check it out.

2) make sure that

- **Net.Tcp Listener Adapter**;
- **Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service**

are running (Windows Services)

Comment: Hi I think that may not be the issue as the service is a local to my machine

Comment: What OS are you starting your app in?

Comment: Sorry, don't have it right under my hands... Look for it somewhere in Administrative Tools

Comment: Also check out the services that I added to my answer.

Comment: any suggestion on this please

Answer (score 2):

Your client config has the URL as

`net.tcp://localhost/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFServiceLibrary/Service2/`

whereas your service is on

`net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFServiceLibrary/Service2/`

The PORT Number is missing in the app.config of your console app client endpoint element.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons as other answers can resolve the problem. But In my case, the problem solved after installing pending windows update.